# No module named tempfile, in everything I do?

Tags: python, module, package, temporary-files

I have been consistingly encountered with this error for many times. Everytime I tried to install a package, there will be an error like this preventing me from downloading every packages

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tempfile'`

I have Conda ( Python 3.8 ) and Python 3.9 on my computer. I'm not sure if that is what caused the conflict of this. And I would be grateful if you guys can suggest me a solution on this error